# Xamarin IOS MonoTouch (Unable to Build Successfully on any profile other than Debug in Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: ios, xamarin

Hi guys I have been struggling with this error for a few days now and I could not find out what's really going on, basically it throws an error **"error : Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com"** i got the complete output of the build in this link

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/87135/error-when-building-in-ad-hoc-profile-to-be-deployed-to-itunes-connect-for-test-flight/p1?new=1

building in Debug mode and iPhoneSimulator works fine and infact can run through the App without any problems... however when I want to use Ad-Hoc so I can produce a signed App for test flight so it can be bug tested by my beta testers I can't because of that error, please note I got no experience in Objective-C and my App in concern is built on C# Mono using Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015, hope you guys can help me out thanks...

Comment: Did you try to clean the solution and rebuild? I would even delete the bin and obj folders for your solution using Finder (Mac) or File Explorer (Windows).

Also make sure you are on the latest stable channel of the Xamarin tools and have the latest Xcode version.

It may also be good to check your project properties for differences between the Ad-Hoc config and the Debug config... obviously you don't want them exactly the same, i.e. debugging should be disabled for the Ad-Hoc build, and the option to create the IPA should be selected for the Ad-Hoc build.

Comment: yes already done that i got the latest xcode , xamarin studio and still the same, already deleted the bin and obj folders, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was caused by a file with register.cs name that caused the issue thanks to the bug helpers of Xamarin i was able to remove the issue and was able to build the IPA file, for those who will encounter this try to watch out for the class names you use on your MonoTouch Projects